# Meteor 1.6.1.1 - searching for WYSIWYG

Tags: docker, meteor, angular5, froala

I am searching for an WYSIWYG editor for my Meteor project.

It's Meteor version 1.6.1.1 with Angular 5.

I have already tried [Froala][1].

Which was working fine local, but after creating a Docker container it showed multiple errors (https://github.com/froala/meteor-froala/issues/27).

So I am looking for either fixing this problem, or another simple/lightweight WYSIWYG editor working with Meteor 1.6.1.1 and Angular 5.

Thank you ;)

Comment: Is your main question about help with froala or about us finding a good editor for you?

Comment: Either one. If you know another working WYSIWYG editor working with Meteor i would try that out. If you know a solution for Froala i would be happy too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest The CKEditor - https://ckeditor.com. I recommend version 4, since I worked with it and I can say that it works very well with Meteor. Put the code (CK Editor library) in the public folder of your project, after that you can simply use it everywhere. It has a download page (https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download) were you can built your editor, add everything that you need and remove the things that you don't need, so it's pretty nice to use it.

Initializing it is that simple:

```
HTML: <textarea id="ck_editor" rows="5">
JS:   CKEDITOR.replace('ck_editor');
```

To get the text content:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.ck_editor.getData()
```

P.S.: I worked with this editor in Meteor 1.5 and I haven't tested it with 1.6, but it should work in the same way. Also I deployed the project on a docker container, without any problems.

Comment: I'm using ck_editor now,
but the ngx-ckeditor" version for npm

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/).

I would recommend self-hosted and you can install it via NPM:

```
npm install tinymce
```

Once you have required the packages see the [docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/first-steps/)